# Java - Actionlistener showing error for a reason I can't see

Tags: java, swing, variables, actionlistener

In the if statement, it is failing to find launchBtn. I'm probably doing something stupidly obvious. Can anyone see what's wrong? The errors are in bold (or highlighted with two **, Here is my code:

```
package launcher;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Window()
    {
    //Creates the blank panel
    super("Launcher");
    setSize(500, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);

    //Create the button variables
    JButton launchBtn = new JButton("Launch Game");
    JButton optionsBtn = new JButton("Launcher Options");

    //Add the buttons to the launcher
    panel.add(launchBtn);
    panel.add(optionsBtn);

    //Add the buttons to the action listener
    launchBtn.addActionListener(this);
    optionsBtn.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getSource() == **launchBtn**)
    {
        **launchBtn**.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launchBtn` has being declared as a local variable with the context of the `Window` constructor.  It has no meaning beyond the constructors scope.

```
public Window()
{
    //...
    //Create the button variables
    JButton launchBtn = new JButton("Launch Game");
```

If you wish to access the variable out side of the constructor, you should make a class instance variable...

```
private JButton launchBtn;
public Window()
{
    //...
    //Create the button variables
    launchBtn = new JButton("Launch Game");
```

This will allow other methods of the `Window` class to reference the variable

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted `launchBtn` and `optionsBtn` to be instance variables of this class, not local variables declared in the constructor.  Move their declarations to outside of the constructor.